# Stack navbar and the next section

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, css-position

I would like to obtain the following result (here obtained by adding `position: fixed` to the navbar, which is not what I want, I want it to disappear when I scroll down):

[image: Screenshot of what I want]

The image is the background of the following div. If I remove the `position: fixed`, the navbar goes up above the image. Is there a proper way to do this with CSS?

I'm using Bootstrap, I don't know if that might help save some time.

Comment: Please post the HTML you used to produce the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To place a navbar at a specific location on the page, and have it scroll with the page, set `position: relative` to the element that contains the navbar, then set `position: absolute` to the navbar.

```css
/* wrapper must have relative position */
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

/* nav must have absolute position */
nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  right: 12px;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.content {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.content img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav>Pretend this is a navbar</nav>
  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/1000" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing! It works. Thanks for the quick answer.